# C getopt_long_only Without Alias

Tags: c, arguments

I have the following C struct long options

```
static struct option long_options[] = {
        {"argument1", required_argument, 0,  0 },
        {"argument2", required_argument, 0,  0 },
        {"argument3", required_argument, 0,  0 },
        {0, 0,  0, 0}
};
```

And i want to use them in this format when i run the program

```
./program -argument1=1 -argument2=test -argument3=test1
```

I don't want ot use the alias of that arguments (if any) for example -a etc. I want to use the full string for that argument like in th example above and take back the value of the argument.

In all examples that i found on the internet they are using the alias of the argument which is only one char

**EDIT**:
Of course the below program is wrong but i want to have in the switch the full argument name not an alias.

```
while ((opt = getopt_long_only(argc, argv,"", long_options, &long_index )) != -1)
{
    switch (opt) {

        case "argument1":
            printf("\n\n%s",optarg);
         break;

    }
}
```

How can i do that?

Thanks

Comment: [strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)?

Comment: Yes but how i can do that. Btw i edited the first post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get at the `struct option` corresponding to the matched argument, use the `long_index` variable you gave `getopt_long()` to index into the `long_options` array. The name string is in there to match.

If what you really want is just a symbolic name for every option then you can just set that in the `val` field of `struct option`. That value is returned from the `getopt_long()` call.

```
enum {
        OPT_ARGUMENT1 = 1000,
        OPT_ARGUMENT2,
        OPT_ARGUMENT3
};

static struct option long_options[] = {
        {"argument1", required_argument, 0,  OPT_ARGUMENT1 },
        {"argument2", required_argument, 0,  OPT_ARGUMENT2 },
        {"argument3", required_argument, 0,  OPT_ARGUMENT3 },
        {0, 0,  0, 0}
};
```

It is better to start the value from beyond the ASCII range so as not to clash with short options (which you don't have in this case) or special characters `getopt_long()` returns.